# Random Zoomed Text within SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssms

For a while now I have been seeing random enhanced text in certain windows of SQL Server Management Studio. It makes it very hard to see the full view of properties in some cases. Please see the screenshots below detailing what I mean.

Is anyone else having this issue? Do we know what causes it? How can I remedy so that everything is the same, normal size?

Here is my version - -     SQL Server Management Studio         15.0.18206.0

[image]

[image]

Comment: You seem to be running SSMS 18.4 from November 2019. Subsequent releases have included various fixes for High-DPI displays - have you tried updating to the latest version?

Comment: I ran the 'check for updates' and installed the latest. Now running 18.8 15.0.18369.0. Same issue still present.